# Base64 encoded string of the Security Credential, which is encrypted using public key

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

I am working on an API that requires encryption of security credentials. I have not done any encryption.

Security credentials are generated by encrypting the base64 encoded password with a public key, a X509 certificate.

The algorithm for generating security credentials is as follows:
Write the unencrypted password into a byte array.
Encrypt the array with the public key certificate. Use the RSA algorithm, and use PKCS #1.5 padding (not OAEP), and add the result to the encrypted stream.
Convert the resulting encrypted byte array into a string using base64 encoding. The resulting base64 encoded string is the security credential.

Can anyone help me achieve this in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer;

```
<?php 
function EncryptData($source) 
{ 
  $fp=fopen("path/to/cert.cer","r"); 
  $pub_key=fread($fp,8192); 
  fclose($fp); 
  $key_resource = openssl_get_publickey($pub_key); 

  openssl_public_encrypt($source,$crypttext, $key_resource ); 
  /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
  return(base64_encode($crypttext)); 
  //echo base64_encode($crypttext);
}

echo EncryptData($pass); 
?>
```